# Any continuous transformation that maps every point in the unit sphere to a different point in the unit sphere?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, geometric-topology, spheres

Can you think of a continuous transformation that maps every point on the (surface of the) unit sphere to a different point on the (surface of the) unit sphere?

More formally, we seek a continuous $f:S^2\rightarrow S^2$ such that $s\neq f(s)\neq -s \forall s\in S^2$.

(No simple rotation of the unit sphere will do, since the points on the axis of rotation are mapped to themselves.)

Is this even possible or is there some topological barrier to accomplishing this?

#### Background

Given some vector $u\in\mathbb{R}^3$ I want to simply derive a vector $v$ that is guaranteed to be non-parallel to $u$. At first glance this seems easy since even a random vector would suffice with probability 1 regardless of input vector $u$. Yet for all this freedom, I can't think of any *continuous* transformation that would work for all vectors.

Comment: Wouldn't a composition of two distinct rotations accomplish this? For example, first rotate by $\theta$ about the x-axis, and then rotate by $\phi$ about the y-axis.

Comment: @Santeri I think that ends up being just a rotation about some other axis.

Comment: I was midway through answering your previous question, but Nate's answer is a basic TLDR. You can't do it continuously on $\Bbb S^n$ for even $n$.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Apologies for deleting that question. I thought I hadn't asked it well enough to get attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x) = -x$ maps every point to a different point.

However, every continuous map $f$ from $S^2$ to itself will have at least one point $x$ for which either $f(x) = x$ or $f(x) = -x$, and in particular $f(x)$ is parallel to $x$. This follows from the [hairy ball theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem).

Comment: @Museful a halfsphere is a disk topologically and then Brouwer gives a fixpoint.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma , that's not correct, $x \mapsto -x$ has no fixed points

Comment: @NoelLundström on the half disk that map is not defined.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma We aren't talking about disks here, we are discussing the sphere $S^2$

Comment: @NoelLundström: There was a deleted comment about working on the half sphere instead.

Answer (score 1):

How about  $f (x)=-x $? ${}{}{}{} $

Comment: True. I should have excluded that case in my question.